# Addition of two classes gives TypeError

Tags: python, class, addition

I  have defined a class that returns the temperature.

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature=0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def _add_(self,other):
        return Celsius(self.temperature + other.temperature)

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value...")
        return self._temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        print("Setting value...")
        self._temperature = value
        
print("my temperature is :",Celsius(37).temperature)
```

What do I need to do if I want to add the temperature of two classes?
If I type: `temp_total = Celsius(37) + Celsius(6)` 
It gives me a TypeError. I thought I could solve this with the '__ add __' expression, but this does not work. Any idea?

I want to type `out = Celsius(37) + Celsius(6)` to give me `out.temperature = 43`.

Comment: Typo: `_add_` -> `__add__` (note the double underscore)

Comment: You misspelled `__add__`.

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice this myself.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need the `__add__` function to override the `sum` operation, if not, Python will try to add both objects without result because they are not built-in data types:

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature=0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value...")
        return self._temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        print("Setting value...")
        self._temperature = value
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Celsius(self.temperature+other.temperature)
        
print((Celsius(3)+Celsius(3)).temperature)
```

**Output:**

```
Setting value...
Setting value...
Getting value...
Getting value...
Setting value...
Getting value...
6
```

Comment: @jeroen Was this answer helpful?